# Dealing with infinite scroll on Instagram channels

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

I am hoping this is the right section to post this query

I am looking for a way to navigate all the way to the bottom of instagram channel pages such as https://www.instagram.com/cars/ The page has a load more button which needs to be clicked and the page needs to be manually scrolled all the way to the bottom. Is there a faster way to get to the bottom of the page instead of having to scroll it all the way?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a website, not programming.

Comment: Scrolling all the way is probably the fastest. Using JavaScript will waste more time than it saves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply execute a javascript method to scroll to the bottom of the page.

`window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);`

This fires the [`scrollTo(x,y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) method passing in `0` fro the x co-ordinate and `document.body.scrollHeight` as the y co-ordinate.

Comment: Many thanks, Nico. Is there a way to execute this through a browser?

Comment: @pb_ng yes.. but you need developer tools open. Most browsers all for arbitrary commands executed. Other than that there isnt much to do on that specific page. Their scructure doesnt even have a link that can be shortcutted.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript

```
var vertical = document.height;
window.scroll(0,vertical);
```